# White border not showing up (css)

Tags: html, css, border

I tried this on UX, apparently that was the wrong place and everyone who answered misunderstood the question anyways.

So, what I want is my image(s) to have a 5px WHITE (#fff) border, with the shadow falling off of the border. I've seen it somewhere, read about it, but for some reason my code isn't working. All I see is the img, and the shadow. NO border in between at all.

This is what I've got:

```
    img {
        border: 5px solid #fff;
        margin: 5px;
        position:relative;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
            opacity: 0.5;
         filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Example 1]

But I want it to look like this:

[image: Example 2]

Comment: I think it has something to do with the opacity, but I'm not sure

Comment: Try adding 5px of padding.

Answer (score 1):

**It is very easy. Add padding to image with the all other properties which you have already defined**

```
img {
        border: 5px solid #fff;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        position:relative;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
            opacity: 0.5;
         filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, what's happening is the border is larger than the size of your shadow.

Your current shadow declaration, `box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;` is telling the `img` to display a shadow that is offset 1px to the left, offset 1px to the top, has 1px amount of blur, and a spread of 1px.

This would be fine, however, your `border: 5px solid white` declaration is greater than that 2px total. You need to increase the size of your shadow.

Here is an example:

```css
img {
  border: 5px solid white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
```

Comment: I altered it accordingly, but still the border isn't showing up, just img straight to shadow. Is it another part of the above css bit that's stopping it?  opacity? position? margin?

Comment: What are the styles like on the parent element? Do they have a set height and width with `overflow: hidden;` set on it? Also, no - position, margin, and opacity would not be affecting it. If anything, you could add `display: block;` to the img declaration, to re-adjust its properties.